# How can I scale/move party of my mesh like it is mirrored or connected?

Tags: transforms, mirror, mirror-modifier

I am modeling the frame of a bike.

I extruded to separated parts of the mesh, now I want to scale them in y direction, meaning away from each other, what doesn't work because they are not connected and if I set the it to median point (picture 2 the faces get bigger what I don't want. Or you could say I want to move them to the outside but not by hand because I want them to be perfectly mirrored.

Should i just delete have of my mesh and mirror it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable symmetry in edit mode with the Axis buttons on the top right. Have one extrusion selected and Grab instead of Scale.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cant make it work. I go into Edit mode. CLick the Y. Select the faces of one extrusion and move them by pressing g. But nothing it happening to the other extrusion

Comment: Check if the object origin is in the center of the geometry. It should work if you put the origin in the split of the fork.

Comment: Yes the origin is in the center of geometry. I just reset it to be sure with Origin>Set Origin>to Geometry. Looking in Y direction it is between the forks but it is obvisously somewhere in the middle of my frame. I just moved it between the forks to be sure but that didnt help either

Comment: if there's a slight difference between the the two parts it may not work any more, maybe before moving the vertices do a Mesh > Symmetrize and choose the good axis in the Operator box (bottom meft of the 3D view)